# Is it possible to expose a published Google Apps Script web-app from one tenant (domain) to another?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-workspace

I have two G-Suite Enterprise accounts/domains/orgs:

- `@example1.com`
- `@example2.com`

I have a GAS script in `@example1.com` that is published as a web-app to [https://script.google.com/a/**example1.com**/macros/s/{scriptID}/exec](https://script.google.com/a/**example1.com**/macros/s/%7BscriptID%7D/exec) and set it so anyone in `@example1.com` can access it.

I want to make it so anyone in `@example2.com` can access it.

I **do not** want to make it accessible to anyone/everyone.

If someone in `@example2.com` tries to go to [https://script.google.com/a/**example1.com**/macros/s/{deploymentID}/exec](https://script.google.com/a/**example1.com**/macros/s/%7BdeploymentID%7D/exec) it redirects them to [https://script.google.com/a/**example2.com**/macros/s/{deploymentID}/exec](https://script.google.com/a/**example2.com**/macros/s/%7BdeploymentID%7D/exec) which obviously will not work since the project is not deployed there. I could deploy the project in `@example2.com` but then it would have a different `deploymentID` so the same URL won't work.

Is there anyway to do what I am after?

Comment: Try this [Allow external sharing with only trusted domains](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6160020?hl=en)

Comment: You can try the option Rubén gives, however you have to manually share the script with all the members in example2.com

Comment: That is for Docs, Sheets, etc. It doesn't seem to work for Google Apps Script web-app URLs.

Comment: Script are considered as files in Google Drive

Comment: I am not talking about the script file. I am talking about the web-app URL for a published script. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a [Group](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9400082) in the Admin console of @example2.com with all the users in the Domain. After that, you can [share the script](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308872) with that Group.

Just make sure that the users [OU](https://support.google.com/a/topic/1227584) (you can create a specific OU for it) have been allowed to [share outside of the domain](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60781).

Or you can add it to a [Share Drive](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9310249) and share it with the Group of domain @example2.com

Comment: I can share the script. But I need to share the web-app published URL. There is no mechanism to share that.

Comment: You can maybe change the App Visibility as "Public" under Gooogle Marketplace listing, and make sure to add the checkmark as unlisted.




This way the users will only be able to install the add-on with the URL.

Comment: This is not for an add-on. This is for a web-app (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).